# Email is in database but my forgot password php script doesn't work and echos out the "Email not registered."

Tags: php, html

I signed up and the same email is in database, but the script fails and echos out the "email is not registered". What could be wrong? no more errors are shown on screen when run, but seems like the code is returning false.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Enter your e-mail:<input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
    $submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_name");
    mysqli_select_db($connection, "db_name");

    if ($submit) {
        $email_check = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($email_check);

        if ($count != 0) {
            $random = rand(100000, 10000000);
            $new_password = $random;
            $email_password = $new_password;
            $new_password = md5($new_password);
            mysqli_query("update users set password='".$new_password."' WHERE email='".$email."'");
            $subject = "Forgot Password";
            $message = "Password successfully changed to $email_password";
            $from = "From:emaile@address.com";
            mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
            echo "Password emailed.";
        } 
        else     
        {
            echo"Email not registered.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: no matter what you find as the root cause of this issue, prefer prepared statements to this SQL implementation.

Comment: Try to change your query execution to this `$mail_check = mysqli_query("the query") OR die(mysqli_error())` and see if any error occours

Comment: did you try to run that exact statement on your database? Also, please sanitize your input before feeding it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and replicate it.

I change also something on the update password from

> mysqli_query("update users set password='".$new_password."' WHERE email='".$email."'");

to

> $update_password =  mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users set password='{$new_password}' WHERE email='{$email}'") OR die(mysql_error());

```
<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

mysqli_select_db($connection, "test");



$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : '';

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';


if ($submit){

$email_check=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'") OR die(mysql_error());

$count=mysqli_num_rows($email_check);

if($count!=0) {

    $random=rand(100000,10000000);

    $new_password=$random;

    $email_password=$new_password;

    $new_password=md5($new_password);

    $update_password =  mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users set password='{$new_password}' WHERE email='{$email}'") OR die(mysql_error());

    $subject="Forgot Password";

    $message="Password successfully changed to $email_password";

    $from="From:emaile@address.com";

    mail($email,$subject,$message,$from);

    echo"Password emailed.";
}else{
    echo"Email not registered.";
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Enter your e-mail:<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and i can select the user with email address save on the database.

check also if your error reporting for php is turn off so that you can see errors that you may encounter during the development

you can use this code to turn it on

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
```

read on this [Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: hi, thanks for fixing my code, but the problem is still on, i get the "Email not registered" echo. Still no errors though..

Comment: Try to print your query on selecting the email address.. And use it to query on your mysql workbench, mysql console or your phpmyadmin directly to check if there is a return

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `'` or replacing them with

```
`
```

. I had the same problem and that solved it.